Inverting a block diagonal matrix with singular blocks
I have a block diagonal matrix where some of the diagonal blocks are zero. The matrix is a representation of an operator, and I'd like to have the inverse of this operator (the individual blocks have low enough conditioning for me to not worry about)
import numpy as np

np.random.seed(42)

N = 10

def composite_operator():
    matrix = np.zeros((3*N, 3*N))
    for n in range(1,N):
        matrix[3*n:3*n+3, 3*n:3*n+3] = np.random.rand(3,3)
    return matrix

The above code block should help to recreate something similar to what I have right now, except that N~1000 and there are multiple zero diagonal blocks distributed along the diagonal in known locations in my case.
In the inverse of this operator, I would like the zero valued blocks to still be zero. Is there a way to do this really efficiently and quickly? Currently I am creating a new composite_operator_inv and populating it with the inverted blocks one by one except for the zero blocks, and I really would love to have a much faster way of doing this.

What do you see as the levers for acceleration? It seems to me that the approach you describe is already optimized (N inversions of 3x3 matrices instead of inverting a 3Nx3N matrix).

I would like the zero valued blocks to still be zero. means you aren't actuallly inverting those blocks, or the whole array.  Removing them from the array before hand, and re 'inserting' them later is, I think the only logical approach.

You can replace the zero matrices by numpy.eye(3). Then inverse the whole matrix and then replace it back to zeros. I believe that inversing the 3*3 matrices will be faster. But its pretty easy to try and check, isn't it?

Yes, you're right. Inverting N 3x3 matrices is faster than inverting one 3Nx3N matrix. And your suggestion is also a good one, replacing the zero blocks with ones!

You can create a matrix with 3 by 3 blocks and inverse it the following way. I added execution time measure to show the efficiency of the method:
import numpy as np
import scipy.linalg as la
import time

np.random.seed(42)
N = 1000  

def composite_operator(N):
    start_time = time.time() 
    blocks = []
    for n in range(N):
        if np.random.rand() > 0.1:  
            blocks.append(np.random.rand(3,3))
        else:
            blocks.append(np.zeros((3,3)))  
    matrix = la.block_diag(*blocks)
    end_time = time.time()  
    print("Time to create the matrix: {:.6f} seconds".format(end_time - start_time))
    return matrix

matrix = composite_operator(N)

def invert_composite_operator(matrix):
    start_time = time.time()  
    N = matrix.shape[0] // 3
    inv_blocks = []
    for n in range(N):
        block = matrix[3*n:3*n+3, 3*n:3*n+3]
        if np.all(block == 0):
            inv_blocks.append(np.zeros((3,3)))
        else:
            inv_blocks.append(la.inv(block))
    inverse_matrix = la.block_diag(*inv_blocks)
    end_time = time.time()  
    print("Time to invert the matrix: {:.6f} seconds".format(end_time - start_time))
    return inverse_matrix

inverse_matrix = invert_composite_operator(matrix)


with
Time to create the matrix: 0.025877 seconds
Time to invert the matrix: 0.057063 seconds

With N = 10000 you still have a reasonable time:
Time to create the matrix: 0.334444 seconds
Time to invert the matrix: 0.424029 seconds

